# Are US / European driver licenses accepted in India?

Tags: india, driving

A couple of friends and I are thinking of travelling to India. The idea is to rent a car for a road trip. I am not sure we can drive there.

Two of us have European drivers licenses, the other a US drivers license. I've been looking around and I found plenty of information about driving inside Europe. Particularly EU (European Union), but not much about other countries.
I even went to a driving school and asked if I could drive in India. They showed me a list of country's, but India is not listed.

In the other hand I've been speaking with some friends that went there and all of them said they had no trouble. The only issue is that they rented scooters/motorbikes.

Are US / European drivers licenses accepted in India?

Comment: @phoog EU - European Union (my mistake, wrote UE first).  Why would they accept them? Driver licenses as far as I know are not universal. They are valid for a given country and optionally accepted by others. I assume, but I am not sure, the principle of reciprocity applys, but that's what I want to find out.

Comment: My second question was just filler to reach the minimum comment length. I'll delete the comment.

Comment: Ever heard of International Driving Permits? Those are translations to your own driving licence and will allow you, in combination with your normal driving licence, to drive in many more countries.  Having an English language driving licence might help in not needing it but they do not cost much and might even be helpful in countries they are not needed.

Comment: 1. Traffic in India is very unruly, think twice before deciding to drive yourself ... but ... 2. Its actually cheaper / more common to rent cars with drivers as well, so you can just get a chauffeured ride instead (idk how this would work for cross city/state trips).

Comment: From what I've heard from multiple friends who have been there, I highly second Alok's comment (and, from personal experience, I'd say the same about the Philippines.) If you're used to U.S. or E.U. traffic, you'll find most South Asian traffic to be **_very_** different (and vice versa.) Personally, I would definitely hire a driver or find some other mode of transit.

Comment: As mentioned by Alok and reirab, you might want to rethink your drive yourself plan.  While out in rural areas it won't be too bad, inside city areas will be a cacophony to drivers used to orderly traffic.  And for the US driver everything is on the wrong side of the road.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

India is a signatory to the [1949 Geneva Convention on Road Traffic](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Geneva_Convention_on_Road_Traffic) and recognizes the standard format [International Driving Permit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Driving_Permit).

As long as you are licensed to drive in your country and your country is also a signatory to the convention, you can get an IDP and use it in India.

Assuming your country is a signatory to the convention, there will be an organization which is authorized to issue these permits in your country.
[This somewhat old page](http://www.drivers.com/article/207/) shows a list of some of the options for different countries.
For example in the USA, the [AAA](http://www.aaa.com/) and [National Automobile Club](http://thenac.com/nonmember_services.htm) both offer this service and in the UK the [AA](http://www.theaa.com/getaway/idp/index.html) and the [Post Office](http://www.postoffice.co.uk/international-driving-permit) are options.